# On the ME Drive, what do the bars mean?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-applied-energistics

There are two bars on the back of the ME Drive. What does each bar mean?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bar on the left indicates the percentage of bytes currently being used. The bar on the right indicate the percentage of types currently being used.

Answer (score -1):

The bar on the **RIGHT** indicates the percentage of bytes currently being used. The bar on the **LEFT** indicates the percentage of types currently being used.